# COM error 0x8007002 (file not found) while executing CoCreateInstance

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have C# assembly with several Com-visible interfaces and classes. This assembly depends on two assemblies without strong name, which can not be signed or modified in any other way. So to register assembly and create tlb file for using in native c++ library I use these post-build commands

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" MyLib.dll /regfile /asmpath:"..\depencies\;C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0;c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727;c:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5"
regedit /s MyLib.reg
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\tlbexp" MyLib.dll /asmpath:"../depencies" /out:MyLib.tlb
```

In my native library in .h file I include tlb file like this:

```
#import "../Build/MyLib.tlb" no_namespace named_guids 
extern ILinkVariableManager *LinkVariables();
```

and in cpp file I implement the method where CoCreateInstance is called:

```
ILinkVariableManager *linkVariables = NULL;

ILinkVariableManager *LinkVariables(){
    if(linkVariables!=NULL)
        return linkVariables ;
    HRESULT result2 = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_LinkVariableManager2,
               NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
               IID_ILinkVariableManager,  reinterpret_cast<void**>(&linkVariables));

    return linkVariables;
}
```

All worked fine until I added some methods to classes and interfaces and changed guids for all interfaces and c# assembly. Now CoCreateInstance returns 0x80070002 error and sets linkVariable value to 0. I see here two possible reasons: my assembly registration way is incorrect and first time all worked accidentally or something went wrong after guids changing (but in .tlh file guids are actual).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding /codebase parameter to regasm.exe post-build command calling.
0x80070002 error signaled of missing filepath to MyLib.dll.

Answer (score 0):

IF you add more types or changed the GUID of the classes in C#, you should  un-register your C# DLL, then register it again with /tlb option and compile the C++ DLL with the tlb.

Un-register: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe /u mydll.dll`

Regeister:  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe/tlb mydll.dll`

Comment: I created new project just now where is one simple class there and tried to use it in new c++ native project, but CoCreateInstance returns the same error.

Comment: does regasm can be used to unregister assemblies without strong name, which is not in cache?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to place the DLL in GAC. If the assembly is not strong names, it will try to find it at the exe path

Comment: error was generated because of missing /codebase parameter, but from current I will unregister all assemblies on debug in pre-build event.